# Symlink pointing at wrong file when executing

Tags: symlink, homebrew

I'm having a strange issue with `hugo` binary installed using `brew` on Ubuntu 18.04. When I run `which hugo` I get `/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/hugo` and when I look at that directory with `ls -la /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin` I get:

```
lrwxrwxrwx  1 myuser mygroup   30 úno 15 09:20 hugo -> ../Cellar/hugo/0.64.1/bin/hugo
```

But when I execute `hugo` it fails with `bash: /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/hugo/0.59.0/bin/hugo: Adresář nebo soubor neexistuje` (Directory or file does not exist).

How can I fix the symlink?

EDIT: Running `/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/hugo` works fine, so it seems that `which hugo` fails to provide correct info for some reason.

Comment: In general terms, remove it and recreate it. If you show us where it's supposed to point someone will even give you the exact command

Comment: Thanks, The `ls -la` command shows it's pointing to `/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/hugo/0.64.1/bin/hugo` which is the correct location. But I then I don't get why executing `hugo` fails like this.

Comment: That's a symlink pointing off to somewhere that you say is wrong. Where should it point?

Comment: I've updated the question with a latest observation

Comment: `which` is a lousy command to use, much better to use `type hugo` or `command -v hugo` if you are using bash.

Comment: I don't see the difference between your failure and your success. But if you're running the right one now you might want just to delete this question.

Comment: Thanks @icarus, `type hugo` reports the alias correctly.

Comment: Does `hash -r` help at all?

Answer (score 0):

Another day, another stupid mistake. I forgot that I had an alias which is pointing to the old version of `hugo`. So the solution is to point it to `/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/hugo` instead.